# how to change height of uiview defined in storyboard

Tags: ios, uiview

**Update:** I ended up implementing the code below into it's own method and then called it from `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`. Doing it from `viewDidAppear` (as suggested) would not resize the view when returning from a segue.

---

I have a UIView defined in a storyboard which I'm using for a header view on my UIViewController. I have a constant in my code for all header views to be 80 units high. I have a tag on the storyboard header view of 200. I thought I could use this tag to get the view, modify the height of the underlying CGRect, and then re-set the header view to the modified CGRect. That doesn't seem to affect the height however. What am I missing?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   UIView *header = [self.view viewWithTag:200];
   CGRect hrect = [header frame];
   hrect.size.height = HEADER_HEIGHT;
   [header setFrame:hrect];
 ...
```

Comment: Please verify that the call to `[self.view viewWithTag:200];` actually returns you something. Make sure that `header` is not nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do that on `viewDidAppear` then call

```
[self setNeedsLayout]
```

Comment: Hey, this works great, but when I rotate or segue off the view it comes back at it's original size. Is there another hook I need?

Comment: Yes you need to recalculate your frames for different orientations check these methods in apple documentation


https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

'willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:, willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration: didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: 
viewWillLayoutSubviews'

Comment: OK, I created a new function named `setupHeader` which sets the height of the header and calls `setNeedsLayout`. It works fine when called from `viewDidAppear` and `willAnimateRotation...` but when I return from a segue, the header is reset to the size defined in the storyboard. That's weird because `viewDidAppear` is getting called after the segue, so `setupHeader` should be getting called as well.

Comment: Think I got it working now. Had to call the resizing code from `viewDidLayoutSubviews` in order to get the view resized after returning from a segue

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using the tag as an NSString. The `tag` property is an NSInteger. Try doing the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIView *header = [self.view viewWithTag:200];// give the tag as an int
    CGRect hrect = [header frame];
    hrect.size.height = HEADER_HEIGHT;
    [header setFrame:hrect];
...
```

Also, make sure the tag you defined in the Storyboard is also `200` and not @"200".

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ahh my mistake, it is an int. Actually, it's a constant but for brevity I edited it for the number I was describing. Good catch.